# Unable to change color for mouse over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color for the background to blue when I mouse over using CSS. I was able to do this yesterday but clueless why it is not working today and its back to white. Been at it for hours and can't figure out whats wrong. Please note I want to do it with CSS, not javascript. It was doable with CSS.

This is the screenshot. I want that white part to be blue when I hover over. Right now it is white when I hover.

[image]

My CSS code which was working correctly, changing it to blue on mouse over.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #c1d100;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a3278;
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/angersleek/pen/KVxNwM?editors=1100)

Added Code Pen. The above code is at CSS section lines 132 - 140. I have copied my exact code but in code pen everything seems default. Black font, white background for the dropdown.

CSS File

```
@font-face {
    font-family: KenzoCustom;
    src: url('../fonts/kenzo-regular.otf');
}

body{
    /*background-color: #eaeaf4;*/
    font-family: KenzoCustom, serif;
}

.formClass{
    max-width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-responsive{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-marpad{
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.form-group{
    text-align: center;
}

.input-center{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-color: #c1d001;
    border-color: #c1d001;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #c1d001;
    border-color: #c1d001;
}

/* remove whitespace after navbar*/
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* navbar-custom */
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #1a3278;
    border-color: #1a3278;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: #1a3278;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #14275d;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #14275d;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    background-color: #14275d;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
    border-color: #14265b;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #14275d;
    color: #c0c0c0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: #14275d;
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
        color: #cccccc;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

.navbar-brand-padding{
    padding: 15px 15px;
}


/* Nav bar drop-down #c1d100 is main BG Green, #fff is text-color, Text BG is #1a3278 blue */
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #c1d100;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a3278 !important;
}

/* Remove border for navbar element*/
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
    border: none;
}

/* Change logo and navbar size when screen size below 768px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    #logo-img img{
        width: 126px;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top{
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top{
        margin-left: inherit;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navitem-margin{
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-font-sz{
        font-size: 24px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbar {
        min-height:210px;
    }

    .logout-margin{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top{
        margin-left: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* You have the option of using SO's runnable snippets or just formatting as code as you've currently done, but the code needs to be in the question, not just on an external page (which can be edited or removed at some later time).

Comment: You're not showing all your code. Essentially, what's going on is that you have a more specific CSS selector _overriding_ the `.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover` rules. Make sure you're not using any `!important`s or anything.

Comment: @BSMP My code is in the question. The code pen is just there to replicate the error to show it in effect. So code pen is not allowed?

Comment: @jperezov Added my CSS code if that would help.

Comment: You only have a few lines of CSS in your question. That isn't enough to duplicate the error. Your MCVE needs to be in the question itself. People need to be able to reproduce the error without following an external link. It's fine to have a codepen to supplement the question but your question can't *require* going off site to understand, replicate, or answer. Right now it does.

Comment: The lines you mention are inside a media query rule @media (max-width: 767px), take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in precedence order of files. The bootstrap is loading after his own style.

The soluction is reviewing the load order or apply `!important` in your rule:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adaBZY?editors=1100

Comment: I see that yours is working but what did you change? My custom stylesheet is loading after bootstrap.

Comment: I put the `!important`:

`.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #1a3278 !important;
}`

Comment: I get what you are saying but for some reason even with !important, its not working for me.

Comment: Well, increase specificity can be considerably better solution. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adaBZY?editors=1100

Answer (score -1):

BootStrap CSS is overriding your CSS. The best option is to make your address more specific. Use below CSS *I just added ul before the class name*

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #c1d100;
}

ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a3278;
}
```

You can use `!important` too, but it is not reasonable practice. I avoid using `!important` as much as possible.

Thanks